# How to make the ListView scroll vertically up automatically when items are added?

Tags: android, listview, button, layout

I am creating a chat application.In this,i have an edittext,a button and a listview.when the text is entered and button is clicked,the item is added to the listview.Here,i want to make the page automatically scroll up when new items are added.The view should not hide behind the keyboard.How to do this ?

Here is my code for button click...

```
 final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText1);
            final ImageButton imb=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
            imb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
            {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View arg0) 
             { 
                String str = et.getText().toString();
                  web1.add(str);
                  Toast.makeText(ShoutSingleProgram.this, "You entered...."+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                  et.setText("");

                    }
            });

            et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                                  if(s.toString().trim().length()==0){
                                    imb.setEnabled(false);
                                   } else {
                                        imb.setEnabled(true);
                                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1. Call this method whenever new test is added.

```
private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
    listView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            listView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

Option 2.

```
listView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
```

Set the head of the list to it bottom

```
listView.setStackFromBottom(true);
```